# Why do I get the error ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '“MAN”' in 'where clause'

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT emp_id, first_name, last_name, job_id
FROM employee
WHERE emp_id NOT IN (SELECT emp_id FROM employee WHERE job_id LIKE “&MAN”);
```

This returns the error `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '“MAN”' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Not just subqueries - SQL uses single-quotes to indicate string content and similar (DateTime)

Comment: Wrong quotes...

Answer (score 2):

The following statement should return your needs. The double quotes is wrong. However you also don't need that subquery to get the data you need.

```
SELECT emp_id, first_name, last_name, job_id
FROM employee
WHERE job_id NOT LIKE '%MAN';
```

When you also have NULL values in the job_id column, those are also filtered out. You can prevent that by including those.

```
SELECT emp_id, first_name, last_name, job_id
FROM employee
WHERE job_id NOT LIKE '%MAN' OR job_id IS NULL;
```